# phpword export text by using variable and text

Tags: php, export, phpword

this is the statement that im trying to combine.

```html
$section->addText("Order No", 'rStyle', 'pStyle');
$section->addText("$x", 'rStyle', 'pStyle');
```

can it be something like

```html
$section->addText("Order No.'$x'.", 'rStyle', 'pStyle');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [PHP String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
$section->addText("Order No.".$x, 'rStyle', 'pStyle');
```